# The last commit did not succeed

Tags: git, github

I did a `git checkout fbd50f60436e058ca33e23d1602faf4163440b0c` to go back to a previous version, then did some modification. Then, I committed the modification (ie, `debugging kpi`), but i cannot see that in the web page of github. Here is the log.

Does anyone know what I should do to let the last modification be the head of everything?

[image]

**Edit 1:**

[image]

Comment: have you tried to push ? editing a pushed commit may be quite hard to push without a merge

Comment: I did `git push -u origin master`

Answer (score 2):

If you checked out a specific commit, you would have entered a 'detached HEAD' state, which means you are no longer on a specific branch.

When you made a further commit, that commit is also not on a specific branch.

You might have needed to run `git reflog` to find your last commit, but it seems you already have the hash.  With the hash, then cherry-pick it on to your working branch:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard 163440b0c
git checkout -b temp-working-branch
git cherry-pick ea14fd
```

Now your work is on `temp-working-branch` and you can merge to `master` if you like:

```
git checkout master
git merge temp-working-branch
```

NB: Edited bc some people don't have `git master` aliased to `git checkout master`

Comment: Have you run `git reflog`?  Is the `ea14fd` commit in there?  I've also suggested in my answer that you do a hard reset to avoid merge conflicts.

Comment: Why did you write `163440b0c` and `ea14fd`? the commit reference should be the first 7 digits, no?

Comment: I'd imagine that *most* people don't have an alias `git master`. :-) @TieCheng: when using a hash ID, you can use as few as four characters, if that specifies one hash ID uniquely. Seven is sort of a good base default but in big repositories you may need even more than seven.